# IBM MFP Adapters - Javascript Array Push() fails

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

CODE:
xxx.push(yyy);

this piece of code is not working in MFP 8 JS ADAPTERS. It always throws *cannot find default value for the object* Sample code has been attached below for better understanding

var xxx = [{
       "MAIN": "ABC",
       "OTHERS":[{
               "NAME": "AAA",
               "INFO": {
                   "reference2": "AA",
                   "reference1": "BB",
                   "reference4": "CC",
                   "reference3": "DD"
               }
        }]
   },
   {
       "MAIN": "BCD",
       "OTHERS":[{
               "NAME": "BBB",
               "INFO": {
                   "reference2": "EE",
                   "reference1": "FF",
                   "reference4": "GG",
                   "reference3": "HH"
               }
        }]
}];

var yyy = [{
   "MAIN": "CDE",
   "OTHERS":[ {
       "NAME": "CCC",
       "INFO": {
         "reference2": "II",
         "reference1": "JJ",
         "reference4": "KK",
         "reference3": "LL"
      }
}];

Answer (score 0):

I do not see a problem doing array push within MFP Javascript adapter.

This is the code I used:

```
function testArrayPush() {

     var xxx = [{ "MAIN": "ABC", "OTHERS":[{ "NAME": "AAA", "INFO": { "reference2": "AA", "reference1": "BB", "reference4": "CC", "reference3": "DD" } }]}, { "MAIN": "BCD", "OTHERS":[{ "NAME": "BBB", "INFO": { "reference2": "EE", "reference1": "FF", "reference4": "GG", "reference3": "HH" } }]}];

     var yyy = [{ "MAIN": "CDE", "OTHERS":[ { "NAME": "CCC", "INFO": { "reference2": "II", "reference1": "JJ", "reference4": "KK", "reference3": "LL" } }]}];

     xxx.push(yyy);

     //xxx.push( [{ "MAIN": "CDE", "OTHERS": [{ "NAME": "CCC", "INFO": { "reference2": "AA", "reference1": "BB", "reference4": "CC", "reference3": "DD" } }]}]);

     return {"resp": JSON.stringify(xxx)};

}
```

There is a structure problem I see in your second array. It is currently:

```
var yyy = [{ "MAIN": "CDE", "OTHERS":[ { "NAME": "CCC", "INFO": { "reference2": "II", "reference1": "JJ", "reference4": "KK", "reference3": "LL" } }];
```

It should be

```
 var yyy = [{ "MAIN": "CDE", "OTHERS":[ { "NAME": "CCC", "INFO": { "reference2": "II", "reference1": "JJ", "reference4": "KK", "reference3": "LL" } }]}];
```

Note the closing '}]'